# sigaction both struct and function

Tags: c++, linux, signals

The following code compiles,

```
struct sigaction sa;
memset (&sa, 0, sizeof (sa));
sa.sa_handler = &handler;
sigaction (SIGRTMIN + 5, &sa, NULL);
```

but if I omit `struct` it gives me error:

> expected ';' before 'sa'

I am using c++ in which using `struct` keyword is not necessory.

How does it work when I use `struct`.

Comment: This looks like you actually have both a `struct sigaction` and a function `sigaction` declared. In this case, the compiler has no way to know you meant the `struct` in the first line unless you tell it.

Comment: Indeed, there are many kinds of statements/expressions that would be ambiguous without knowing which identifier is a type and which not. So the compiler can't guess whether you are using `sigaction` to mean a type or function, you have to tell it. That's also the reason for `typename` before dependent types in templates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C, structure tags were in a separate name space than other
names, so they couldn't conflict.  In C++, there is a special
hack in the language to support this: in addition to the usual
function overloading, you can have two identical symbols in the
same scope, provide one is a type name specifying a class type
or an enum.  When the name is looked up, the compiler will
choose the one which is *not* a type name unless the name
immediately follows a class-key (`class`, `struct` or `union`)
or the keyword `enum`.

Comment: I tried for int also and it worked, thank you for such a nice explanation